# Redirecting after 5 minutes to locked screen page

Tags: php, jquery, redirect

Upon not being active on my [administration panel](http://rafflebananza.com/admin/index.html?), I would like the page to redirect to the [locked screen page](http://rafflebananza.com/admin/lock.html) passing over the page URL they have come from so that upon clicking the login, they can be redirected back to the last page they were on.

I also need to know how to set a global variable so that if they are not active and end up on the locked screen page, they cannot access any other page, instead redirecting them and passing over that page URL to redirect back.

1. How to know whether they have been inactive for 5 minutes.
2. How to set a global php/JQuery variable
3. How to read this variable from any page
4. How to redirect and upon unlocking redirect back

There is currently no login system at this moment of time, no password is required to test this page.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="seconds_refresh; URL=myurl">
```

Clearly you would fill in the seconds_refresh with the seconds until the page goes to the "myurl" which can be what ever. Have php print it out on a submission or just have it simply be in an HTML page.

Comment: Does this refresh after no page activity?